# Show that $g$ is injective if $f\circ g$ and $f$ are both injective

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I ran into a problem when I am trying to studying my review question. I am not sure how to prove the following:

Suppose $A,B,C$ are sets. $f: A \to B$, $g: C\to A$, $f\circ g: C\to B$. If $f\circ g$ and $f$ are both one-to-one (injective), then $g$ is injective.

Comment: What are thoughts you have?

Comment: my thought is that it is false.

Comment: In the conditions "$f$ is injective" is a red herring; it is not needed.

Answer (score 3):

If $g$ is not injective, then there is $x,y\in C$ with $g(x)=g(y)$ and $x\neq y$. It follows that $f\circ g(x)=f \circ g(y)$, so that $f\circ g$ is not injective.

Comment: A proof by contrapositive.

Comment: @JasperLoybut  how can you proof it formally? I think this is just the inverse of it